# How to git stash only staged files?

Tags: git

During interactive rebase, I often find I want to make some changes appear BEFORE the current changeset, e.g. if I have:

```
A->BCD->E
```

I want to move to:

```
A->D->BC->E
```

So I do an interactive rebase, and edit the relevant changeset.  So I'd like to be able to:

1. `reset --soft`
2. commit BCD
3. unstage D
4. stash the staged changes
5. commit D
6. pop the stash
7. commit

Is this possible, or is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the question on the official git mailing list, but didn't got a real answer. http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Proposal-for-git-stash-add-staged-option-td7629171.html

Here is what I use now :

It makes it possible to do `git cstash "optional message"` which will stash all your `staged` files into a stash.
It handles both dirty and clean states.

```
#/bin/sh
#
function evil_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git diff --shortstat 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "" ]] && echo "dirty" || echo "clean"
}

function create_stash {
    # And convert into a stash
    if [ "$1" == "" ]
    then
        # Unnamed stash
        git stash
    else
        # Named stash
        git stash save "$1"
    fi
}

IS_DIRTY=$(evil_git_dirty)

echo "$IS_DIRTY"

if [ "$IS_DIRTY" == "clean" ] 
then
    create_stash "$1"
    exit 0
fi

# Put staged files in a tempory commit
git commit -m 'temporary, will be stashed soon' --no-verify
# Put everything else in a temporary stash
git add .
git stash
# Remove commit
git reset HEAD^1

git add .

create_stash "$1"
# Pop the temporary stash
git stash pop stash@{1}
git reset .
```

Comment: I haven't read the entire script, but two things jump at me. 1) Although your shebang specifies `sh`, you use bashisms such as `[[`. 2) `[ -z "$1" ]` is more idiomatic than `[ "$1" == "" ]`.